# Parsing custom text tags using JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to search a `<div>` of a specific class for a simple text system, then store the text.

Basically, there will be a div, and inside the div there might be some text like:

`[ALERT](TEXT TO STORE HERE)`

I'd like to search a div for the ALERT tag, then store any text inside the () under a variable if it exists, and push an alert to the console if it's found.

However, while I can easily find the first part, [ALERT], I cannot figure out how to find the whole string, or store the containing text. I think it should end up something like:

```
var alerttext = $("#result").find("[ALERT](.)")=(function()
{
return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

However, that seems pretty far off, and definitely isn't working.

Edit: The html would resemble:

```
<div id="bbb" class=""><p id="aaa">text test text

[ALERT](TEXT TO STORE HERE)

More text down here

</p></div>
```

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.text()` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\n.+\()|(\).+\n+\s+$)/g` to replace input string up to `(` , from `)` to end of input , remove newline, space characters at beginning and end of matched string

```js
var arr = [];

$("#bbb").text(function(i, text) {
  if (text.indexOf("[ALERT]") >= 0) {
    var match = text.replace(/(\n.+\()|(\).+\n+\s+$)/g, "");
    arr.push(match);
    console.log(arr);
  };
  return text
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="bbb" class="">
  <p id="aaa">text test text [ALERT](TEXT TO STORE HERE) More text down here
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly- I should have known it was gonna come down to regex. Thanks for your help!